# Simultaneously Requests in Nodejs (maybe code running twice at the same time)

Tags: node.js, performance, python-requests

I would like to ask you something. So I have my NodeJS application which receives like 100 objects every second through WebSocket (or even more). For every object received, I check if it already exists in the database, and if don't, I store it.

What I think sometimes happen is that I receive the same object more than one time through the WebSocket almost simultaneously and it's too fast that it stores 2 of the same objects on the database. (I mean, the query where I check if it exists or not is being ignored, probably because the code is running more than one time simultaneously). I don't know, something like this.

I could use a queue to avoid that or something like this but I need this data stored almost instantly as my website works with real-time data.

I just would like to know how it works, if the code is really running twice at the same time for example, and maybe another way I could solve it without using the queue, to store it instantly. Something like this...

Comment: Depends on the database you use. You can handle that in your application or let the database do the job (if it supports it). You didnt say what kind of db you are using.

Comment: @Marc it is mongodb.

Comment: Create a index for your field and set unique to true: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/index-unique/

Answer (score 0):

You will need to implement a concurrency handler mechanism.

I suspect that basically what is happening to you is:
As you first query MongoDB to know if the document already exists and then if it does not exists your NodeJS inserts such document into MongoDB.
Let's say we have request A, and request B, both asking almost at the same time if the record already exists in DB (and the record does not exists) then both of then are going to: first receive a:

> no such record exists in the db

And then both are going to insert the same record. You can use MongoDB unique indexes and also functions like `findAndModify` (which handles concurrency)

If you are using mongoose, `findAndModify` becomes the `findOneAndUptade` method.